# Find Subplot Number from Matplotlib Pick Event

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive

So I have three matplotlib subplots. I can use a pick event to pull off and re-plot the data in any one of the subplot. Is it possible to read the pick event and to find out what subplot number was selected?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: Unfortunately I cant do that because its just too big. Here are some relevant snippets that I can put in the question itself.

Comment: self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.select_axes)

def select_axes(self, event):
        if event.mouseevent.button == 1:
            if isinstance(event.artist, matplotlib.axes.Axes):
                axes = event.artist

            for line in axes.get_lines():
                        plt.figure()
                        plt.plot(line.get_xdata(), line.get_ydata())
                        plt.show()

I cant seem to format this code correctly, basically I can pull off the plotted data but I cant tell which subplot it came from.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than dumping code in the comments. It's unreadable in this state.

Comment: You have the `Axes` object so you can probably do what ever you want with it.  Failing that, you can use `Axes` as keys in dictionaries to map back to what ever you want.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. Ali, I am new here and I wasnt sure how to edit the question. I apologize about the difficult to read response.

Comment: Tcaswell, thanks for your reply. I ended up using exactly this approach and putting the axes in a dictionary I can reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the axes in a list or dictionary when creating. Then when a pick event has occurred, match the pick event axis to the dictionary.

Thank you all.